# how to tell typescript the value exist?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code

```
   options: { url?: string } = {};
   if (!Checker.present(this.options.url)) {
      throw new Error('Options must have a url');
   }
   new CustomUrl(this.options)
```

but I get an error cause `CustomUrl` **require** an url, and my interface is optional.

My checked function looks like this

```
  static present(value: any) {
    return value !== undefined && value !== null;
  }
```

but how do I tell typescript that I checked, and that value is present ? (counting that I can't use the `!` in my code

Comment: If you're OK with changing the checking part of it, look up custom / user-defined type guards in the TS docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `as` to assert that the object has a `url` property:

```
new CustomUrl(this.options as { url: string });
```

For the more general case, you can use `& { url: string }` to combine the optional interface with a required `url` property:

```
new CustomUrl(this.options as Options & { url: string });
```

where `Options` is the type of the initial `options`.

Comment: ok for this simple exemple, but if in my case the type is very big, do I have to make two interface one with ? and one without ? Is the only way ?

Comment: You can also use `&` to combine with a required property.

Answer (score 1):

One way is.
You need to assert the existence of the url inside the CustomUrl function, not outside.

```
interface IOpt{
    { url?: string } 
}

function CustomUrl(opt:Required<IOpt>){
}
```

Another way.
You need to change the CustomUrl parameter to Required.

```
interface IOpt{
    { url?: string } 
}

function CustomUrl(opt:Required<IOpt>){
}
```